# How to increase precision of color ramp affecting model?

Tags: node-editor, units

I created color ramp with 10 colors. Every color point has typed position as multiplication of 10%. Values are: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and so on.

[image: Color ramp with colors offset at the same distance: 10%]

The plane was divided 9 times, so the results are: 10 faces with the exact same size.
[image]
The colors don't appear on a model precisly.
Typing 0.6 at the blue color point position don't make blue color appear on model at exacly 60% objects width - it gives close representation, but it is the same final result on model as typing 0.598 or 0.601.

[image]

I want my color ramp to have higher precision representation on model. How to change that?

Comment: Probably an issue with the origin location. This is not enough information to solve it outright through. But try moving your object in edit mode. uploading the blend file is the best way for help.

Comment: Color Ramp is implemented with a 256x1 texture, so you can replace it with your own texture of whatever width you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a known issue, ColorRamp marker positions are rounded to the next higher multiple of 1/256, leading to unexpected output, especially when set to 'Constant' interpolation. There is nothing you can do about it except adding burninate token here:

https://developer.blender.org/T74198

If you want to be precise, you should switch to math nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you need, but it could be as simple as this ..

[image]